# Sketch of heap usage prior to algorithm implementation

Tags: heap, algorithm

I'm trying to have an idea of what would be the heap usage of a [certain algorithm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367784/grouping-objects-according-to-a-set-of-fields) in Salesforce, given different inputs in order to determine if I should implement it async or sync.

I am aware that heap size is calculated at runtime, that it is not the most precise thing ever and that it depends on the fields I retrieved, etc. Regardless, I'm just trying to make a sketch, so it doesn't matter if it's not very accurate.

Let's assume **the records we'll work with are Contacts**, that I've retrieved the **Id and 5 emails fields** and that I'll be sorting them in a map.

So, if I have the a `Map<String, List<Contact>>` with 25.000 entries where each list only has one element with the before mentioned fields, how can I calculate it more or less?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is going to be highly variable based on the actual inputs involved, mostly because of the strings.

We can calculate the bare minimum though. The map itself will require 4 bytes. Keys are 4 bytes plus the length of the string, so 100,000 bytes plus the length of the strings. The List itself will use 4 bytes, so another 100,000 bytes of storage, and each index will use 4 bytes, so another 100,000 bytes of storage. Contact records also use 4 bytes, plus variable amounts for each field, so 100,000 bytes.

This means that 400,004 bytes are used just for the data structures. Presuming you have an Id for each contact, 24 bytes to store the ID, or 600,000 bytes. Assuming each of the five email fields are custom, they take up the field's length plus 4 bytes minimum, so a worst case scenario of about 5,875,000 bytes assuming all the fields are null and field names are maxed out at 40 characters (the `__c` may overflow to 43 total characters in the file name, thus 4 would be the minimum).

If each email were 100 characters long, you might expect usage of another 10,000,000 bytes of heap to be used. It's up to you to figure out how much storage would actually be used, perhaps by exporting the data and averaging out the lengths. Assuming the keys were a modest 10 characters each, that's another 250,000 bytes.

At minimum, though, you're looking at 1,000,004 bytes for structure plus 1,000,000 assuming the field names were the minimum one character each, or 2,000,004 bytes of total memory used, and then adding each of the string lengths together. Note that if you can store references to strings, those strings will be reused and not use any extra memory, so things might not be as bleak as they first appear; if you can avoid string manipulation, you might only incur 4 bytes per key instead of larger values (but those costs will be applied elsewhere in the heap).

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to use some async stuff then... thanks for the info. Very valuable!